# flutter audioplayer not working after hot restart

Tags: android, windows, flutter, flame, flutter-audioplayers

I use `audioplayers` https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers 3.0.1 under Windows and native Android.
Under Android everything works perfectly fine but I have issues under windows.

**What works**: I can play my audio (mp3) file as often as I want. (Windows and Android)

**What doesn't work**: If I do a `Hot Restart` and I again want to play the exact same audio file it results in the following error. (ONLY on Windows)

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\<mypath>.mp3' (OS Error: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.

, errno = 32)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:80:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:101:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:249:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:131:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I use the player like that `_player.play(AssetSource('<file>.mp3'));`

Additionally I do dispose `_player` when the widget is disposed. (gets called - verified with log output)

Am I using the player in a wrong way?

Does `Hot Reload` do something special I didn't know until now?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to properly dispose the previous players in hot reload and windows only allows one process to read the file at once this is currently not possible, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1120#issuecomment-1428868670).

Comment: thanks for your reply; shouldn't the player's dispose method clean the file-access?

Comment: The problem is that hot reload doesn't trigger dispose

Comment: You can see more information about it in the link that I added to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply; 
yes, hot-reload doesn't trigger it, okay;
but I do 'manually' call dispose before triggering hot-reload - shouldn't this also release the ressource?

Comment: It should yes, how do you manually call dispose before triggering hot reload? There is no lifecycle event that you can hook into there. Or do you do it from a debug console?

Comment: I called it's dispose method when the widget did dispose - I put there an debug output to 'verify' it is called.